# ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin CORS Policy JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, cross-domain, instagram

This is the image URL I got from an api

https://scontent-jnb1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e15/242204298_1728375270686500_5634415857798350440_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-jnb1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=3O8LpuGJsdUAX_E1Dxz&edm=AHlfZHwBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=0a22779e81f47ddb84155f98f6f5f75f&oe=6148F26D&_nc_sid=21929d

this is my HTML

```
<img src="https://scontent-jnb1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e15/242204298_1728375270686500_5634415857798350440_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-jnb1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=3O8LpuGJsdUAX_E1Dxz&edm=AHlfZHwBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=0a22779e81f47ddb84155f98f6f5f75f&oe=6148F26D&_nc_sid=21929d">
```

I see the image when I go to the URL, directly through the browser. But it is not showing up on my website

When I checked the Debug Console I get this error.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin
```

when I googled this the problem might be due to some CORS Policy issue.

How to load this image on my website without messing with the policy and stuff...?

```html
<img src="https://scontent-jnb1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e15/242204298_1728375270686500_5634415857798350440_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-jnb1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=3O8LpuGJsdUAX_E1Dxz&edm=AHlfZHwBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=0a22779e81f47ddb84155f98f6f5f75f&oe=6148F26D&_nc_sid=21929d">
```

Comment: I don't think that's a CORS issue - CORS has to do with content retrieved using javascript (and there's no javascript in your single line of code) - why are you using a `video` tag for an image anyway?

Comment: @Bravo I don't know the real problem, but that error pointed to CORS policy when I googled it. Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question.

Comment: @RandomKindle Hey did you ever figure out and successfully bypass this. Im also trying to access from instagram

Answer (score 25):

this should fix it

```
helmet({
      crossOriginResourcePolicy: false,
    })
```

Comment: Can you explain this code?

Comment: Refer to this thread for an explanation of why above added flag: https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues/343#issuecomment-1006259994

TLDR; In later versions of Helmet package, the flag `crossOriginResourcePolicy` has been added as true by default.

Comment: I should put this code in frontend or backend, I have already added `res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` in backend

Comment: This worked perfectly with reactjs 16+

Comment: This is my case, thanks. The problem from backend, not frontend

Answer (score 22):

I was getting the same error while fetching images from different api.

I fixed the error by adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` in image tag.

Just add `crossorigin="anonymous"` in your img tag like:

```
<img crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://example.com/image.jpg">
```

this should resolve the error.

Comment: This is not the solution for above question

Answer (score 15):

You need to set `cross-origin-resource-policy: "cross-origin"`.
If you're using helmet in your Express App.
try this:

```
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
```

For more information read any of these [CORP](https://resourcepolicy.fyi/) and [HelmetJS](https://helmetjs.github.io/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use helemt package

```
const helmet = require("helmet");

app.use(
  helmet({
    crossOriginResourcePolicy: false,
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a CORS issue, and can only be solved server-side.

The response has the header `cross-origin-resource-policy: same-origin` which tells us that the resource can be accessed only by the same origin (when it's called inside a html page, using modern browsers)

You might host the image in another place to use it.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)

Comment: I can't host the image anywhere else. I get image URLs through an API from the Instagram server. Is there any other option?

Comment: Actualy, you could use a proxy that would make the request for you, and get the response from this proxy. But I don't know how if there are any services like that, and the response would be twice lazy...

Comment: Thank You, I with look for something like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great proxy out there used just for this - bypassing a CORS block. The source code is here: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere, and you would use it like this:

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://scontent-jnb1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e15/242204298_1728375270686500_5634415857798350440_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-jnb1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=3O8LpuGJsdUAX_E1Dxz&edm=AHlfZHwBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=0a22779e81f47ddb84155f98f6f5f75f&oe=6148F26D&_nc_sid=21929d`
basically just adding the CORS-Anywhere URL before your actual image URL.

If you get rate limited by that website, try `https://circumvent-cors.herokuapp.com/`, this is one that I have deployed from the GitHub source code, no modifications and I do not think it should rate limit you.

The image you provided has expired, so if you were to give me an example of what API you were using to get the image, or another image blocked by CORS that maybe doesn't expire, I could properly test this and maybe find another answer, if this one doesn't work.

Cheers!

Comment: `Missing required request header. Must specify one of origin,x-requested-with`
Why is this showing up?

Answer (score 1):

This way can fix ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE. (by https://stackoverflow.com/a/71878799/12117869)

> this should fix it
>
> helmet({
> crossOriginResourcePolicy: false,
> })
> this

BTW,if happen ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE issue, Maybe the Reason :
It's a chrome bug. It will happen on the chrome 80 - 85 version. but it was fixed on the 86 version.

> [CORS] Set preflight request mode correctly
>
> CORS preflight request mode was set to kNoCors up until now, and with
> cross-origin-embedder-policy: require-corp CORS preflights fail unless
> a CORP header is attached. Fix the bug.

same issue :
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1116990#c21

google fix commit: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/ed257e2b7df1d3bdcd95d8687bcbd786bc48e717

Answer (score 0):

Just add crossorigin="anonymous" in your tag like:

```html
<video id="myVideo" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://xxxxxx....."></video>
```

Comment: Please don't add the same answer twice, [Manish Rai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72562100/2822719) has already posted the same hint.

Answer (score 0):

Config your BE app with helmet like this! It worked for me.

```
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this attribute in your img tag

```
crossOrigin ="anonymous"
```