# html img tag not showing the imge with url

Tags: html

```html
<img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/284331511_285164750412909_4330553454694541702_n.webp?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=4C1j0IU_QckAX8t_Wq4&edm=AHlfZHwBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT8mdlB1CXl9w0lx9-w70oaEE2le67xU9jLsheyPGqmo1Q&oe=6298BE60&_nc_sid=21929d" alt="test"/>
```

me url

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/284331511_285164750412909_4330553454694541702_n.webp?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=4C1j0IU_QckAX8t_Wq4&edm=AHlfZHwBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT8mdlB1CXl9w0lx9-w70oaEE2le67xU9jLsheyPGqmo1Q&oe=6298BE60&_nc_sid=21929d
```

Please help me

Comment: the problem is with your src path. make sure you have inserted the right url

Comment: I think you are running into CORS, Cross-Origin Request is blocked. Wherever that image is hosted has a strict policy to prevent anyone hotlinking it.

Comment: This is a *SERVER* issue.  If you run your snippet and look at the result in [Chrome Developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) (FN-12), you'll see this: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin`.  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69244046/421195 or here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/failed-to-load-resource-neterr_blocked_by_response/ for more details.

Comment: you can only access within the same host according to cross-origin-resource-policy set to same-origin. if you want to access this from any website then relax server cross origin resource policy with allow cross-origin.

Answer (score 0):

Content providers sometimes have processing or other methods to prevent images from being hot-linked. An alternative is to download the image and host it with your web content (Conforming to copyright laws of course).