# react app does not show images from express api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, vite, express-fileupload

I'm using a node/express API to store users/clients, in one of the functionalities I need to upload an image to set the `Brand logo`, the image uploads well, and the image URL response is correct, if I put the image URL in browser load and shows perfect, but the `<img />` tag in my react-app does not render the image correctly.

To upload files, I'm using `express-fileupload` library.

Here are my configs and code:

`app.js`

```js
...imports and other things
//settings
app.set('port', config.port);
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

//middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(
    fileupload({
        createParentPath: true,
    })
);
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(i18n.init);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

`client.routes.js`

```js
...other routes
clientRouter.post('/clientes/logos/upload', uploadLogoImg);
```

`client.controller.js`

```js
...other controller functions
export const uploadLogoImg = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (!req.files) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'No se ha seleccionado ninguna imagen',
            });
        } else {
            const logo = req.files.logo;
            const appURL = config.appURL;

            await logo.mv(`./src/public/uploads/logos/${logo.name}`);

            return res.status(200).json({
                success: 'Imagen subida correctamente',
                logoUrl: `${appURL}/uploads/logos/${logo.name}`,
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            error:
                error.message ||
                'Ha habido un error subiendo la imagen, contacte con el administrador',
        });
    }
};
```

For my frontend I'm using vite/react app, rendering an `<img/>` tag with `logoUrl` in src attribute, see images below:

Image file uploaded to server:

[image: Image uploaded to server folder]

Image requested from URL in browser:

[image: browser image]

Image rendered in `<img/>` tag on react mui-datatable (the first 2 images for other brands come from the official web of the brand):

[image: logo IMG on front]

`<img/>` tag on rendered HTML:

[image: img tag rendered]

I don't know  what I'm doing wrong, please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit, your spelling is wrong in url pulic >> public.

Comment: @sedhal Edited: sorry, I uploaded an incorrect image for that, please check the new one.

Thanks.

Comment: are you getting any error on the browser console ?

Comment: @Kaneki21 no, no errors on console, I've tried to render an HTML file to a single H1 and IMG tags and the image renders well, but in react not.

Comment: check the network tab if any request is happening

Comment: @Kaneki21 I'm using Morgan in my API and the console sends this: `GET /uploads/logos/LOGO-Mercedes-Benz.jpg 200 3.584 ms - 20129`, the file is retrieved correctly, right?

Comment: No, got to browser devtools->network tab and check the request, click on it and see the preview, if the image is shown or not

Comment: Sorry, network tab viewed, and the request happens, but in the preview of the file says: `No data found for resource with given identifier`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246408/discussion-between-josh-rodriguez-and-kaneki21).

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue with a simple attribute to the `<img/>` tag, adding `crossOrigin='anonymous'`.

Now the logos from backend can be rendered correctly:

[image: fixed]

I've found the solution
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72562100/10726558)

Thanks a lot for your suggestions and time.