# Html does not display image from url sorce

Tags: html, image, url

Simple question, I have this source URL I need to display it on IMG tag on HTML page, but the URL does not return a response when I paste it in img tag is with GET 200 but no IMG response if I open in browser the image is in the response. How to render the image from this URL.

> https://scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/118728599_236868367676627_1501714039502593397_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150&_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=111&_nc_ohc=3xkXtM3P--8AX81FGxo&edm=AMKDjl4BAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfC6BQkNCq70zq-OBz0eawyN4pDD8D8kNDiWxfURfs8BYw&oe=636126BA&_nc_sid=1fe099

Comment: If you view the Developer Console, you will see an error concerning the blocked response. Include this error in your post. Also try the solutions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69243166/err-blocked-by-response-notsameorigin-cors-policy-javascript)

Comment: That should be the solution is CORS related.I will try the answers from the post you share.