# ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE Error loading image from Nodejs API

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am developing Rest API using Nodejs All my routes are working fine but I can't load images.
I am getting this error net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin 200 (OK).
Below is my Route config class.

```
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import express, { Response, Request } from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import helmet from "helmet";
import { Message } from "./messages";
import Routes from "./routes/routes";
import compression from "compression";
import sseRoute from "./routes/sseRoute";

class App {

    public express: express.Application;
    public msg: Message | undefined;
    constructor() {
        this.express = express();
        this.msg = new Message();
        this.middleware();
        this.routes();
    }

    // Configure Express middleware.
    private middleware(): void {
        this.express.use(cors());
        this.express.use(helmet());
        this.express.use(compression());
        this.express.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
        this.express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: false }));
    }

    private routes(): void {
        // this.express.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
        this.express.use('/logo', express.static('public/uploads/business/logo'));
        this.express.use('/business_profile', express.static('public/uploads/profile/business'));
        this.express.use('/media/photos', express.static('public/uploads/media/photos'));
        this.express.get("/", (_req: Request, res: Response, _next) => {
            return this.msg?.error(res, 'Typescript App works!!', 404);
        });
        this.express.use(sseRoute);
        // user route
        this.express.use("/api", Routes);

        // handle undefined routes
        this.express.use("*", (_req: Request, res: Response, _next) => {
            return this.msg?.notFound(res, 'Make sure url is correct!!!');
        });
    }
}

export default new App().express;
```

Please I need help

Comment: does this one solves your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69243166/err-blocked-by-response-notsameorigin-cors-policy-javascript ?

Comment: Thank you very much. But I already solved my problem anyway. Before your comment.